# ffmpeg commands not working in micromax android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am able to execute ffmpeg commands on android devices like Samsung,LG and Sony but in Micromax it's not working. I have built ffmpeg library for arm processor. I could not collect the log because I am not able to connect the device. I have following questions on this,
1) Why it's not working on Micromax?
2) I do not want to show my app on other device apart from ARM based android device, is it possible to control?

The below configuration I have used while building ffmpeg,

## !/bin/bash

cd ffmpeg

export TMPDIR=tmp
mkdir -p $TMPDIR

## Android NDK Location

NDK=/Users/sunitha/Downloads/android-ndk-r9c

ANDROID_API=android-9
SYSROOT=${NDK}/platforms/${ANDROID_API}/arch-arm
PREBUILT=${NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86
CROSS_PREFIX=${PREBUILT}/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
ARM_INCLUDE=${SYSROOT}/usr/include
ARM_LIB=${SYSROOT}/usr/lib
PREFIX=../build
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS=" -marm -march=armv6 "
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=

## Location of lame's static installation

MP3LAME=../libmp3lame
X264=../libx264

./configure \
 --arch=arm \
 --target-os=linux \
 --enable-cross-compile \
 --cross-prefix=${CROSS_PREFIX} \
 --prefix=${PREFIX} \
 --sysroot=${SYSROOT} \
 --extra-cflags=" -I${ARM_INCLUDE} -I${MP3LAME}/include -I${X264}/include -DANDROID ${OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS}" \
 --extra-ldflags=" -L${ARM_LIB} -L${MP3LAME}/lib -L${X264}/lib" \
 --disable-debug \
 --enable-libmp3lame \
 --enable-libx264 \
 --disable-ffplay \
 --disable-ffprobe \
 --disable-ffserver \
 --enable-avfilter \
 --enable-decoders \
 --enable-demuxers \
 --enable-encoders \
 --enable-filters \
 --enable-indevs \
 --enable-network \
 --enable-parsers \
 --enable-protocols \
 --enable-swscale \
 --enable-gpl \
 --enable-nonfree \
 ${ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG}

cd ..

Comment: Please tell the model of Micromax in which it is not working !

Comment: Model no -A111, Android version -4.1.2

Comment: Can you add `configure_ffmpeg.sh` ?

Comment: I have updated my question with config info.

Comment: Have you found solution here???